# why almost of application hare released with DLL

Tags: dll

We find most of application are released with many DLLs and finding an application published in an individual excuteable file is hard. I know some of using DLL advantage , like enabling developing team using multiple programing language or reducing resources usage when a couple of functions are called in some aplications

but most of applications have been published while they dont share any library with another application neither developed by multiple languages

in other word , why we should release our product in nummerious files while we are able to release it in a single file

many thanks

Comment: Not having to wait for a monster EXE file to be built is very high on the list of advantages.

Comment: you mean it is for time saving in build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a few reasons, these come to mind;

- Smaller updates (easier to update a DLL than an entire application)
- Unused code isn't loaded (if you're not using a DLL, it takes no memory while it may if integrated)
- Easier to reuse code (even if you're not sharing between applications, it may make unit testing easier for example, and it may be used in several product SKUs)